# Is there something similar to "Mark Directory as resources root"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a WPF .NET application in C# and a PowerShell script I want to execute. I placed the PowerShell script in the directory "Assets". But when I build my program the PowerShell script is stored in plain text in a folder called "Assets" which makes it vulnerable to users who change the PowerShell script at runtime or even before the launch.

So my question here is, is there something similar to "Mark Directory as resources root" like we know it from the JetBrains IDEs? So it is "not visible" to the user?

Any help or knowledge sharing is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you not just add the file as a resource and extract it at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET assemblies can have an arbitrary number of embedded resources, which are stored alongside code inside the executable. It is not possible, to my knowledge, to mark a whole directory this way, but individual files can be configured to be embedded:

[image: Setting Embedded Resource on a file]

Alternatively, this is how it is defined in the .csproj file:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="some_file.txt">
      <LogicalName>some_file.txt</LogicalName> <!-- optional -->
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This resource is identified by its name, allowing you to retrieve it as a stream:

```cs
var assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly; // or any other class that is in the same assembly
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("some_file.txt");
```

You can also retrieve the collection of all embedded files' names via `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()`, so you can simulate something like directory search by filtering names having a common prefix, for example.

Comment: Thanks, but somehow my script is not getting embedded. When I print this line of code: `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` I am getting an empty String array. I set the Build Action to Embedded Resource just like in your screenshot. Any ideas about what I may have missed? (PS: I put the script in the root directory of the project, is this wrong?)

Comment: @ProRedMax Is the "File Name" field filled?

Comment: yes it is (but not changeable/greyed out)

Comment: @ProRedMax Hmm, I am not sure why; it should be changeable (to specify the name of the resource).

Comment: Could you show me what your .csproj file looks like?

Comment: @ProRedMax Sure, I've added that to the answer. I was actually mistaken about the File Name field; it seems to move the file if I change it... but I had an old project that used the `<LogicalName>` element so maybe that could fix the issue.